# Firebase não comunica com app

Tags: android

Recentemente comecei a trabalhar com o firebase. Estou seguindo um tutorial na internet, e na minha aplicação o status não atualiza. Sei que com o Firebase ele atualiza na hora.
Estou trabalhando na rede interna da empresa e contem firewall. 
Será que o firewall está bloqueando ?

Se sim, alguém sabe qual a porta ?

Comment: Você confirmou que isso só acontece na rede da sua empresa?

Comment: Ainda não. Comecei a fazer agora na empresa e me deparei com isto. Vou tentar hoje novamente em casa.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, pode ser que seu firewall esteja bloqueando. Leia aqui este artigo de [Implementação do protocolo de servidor de conexão](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server?hl=pt-br).

> Se sua organização tiver um firewall que restrinja o tráfego de/para a
>   Internet, é preciso configurá-lo para permitir a conectividade com o
>   FCM para que os aplicativos clientes do Firebase Cloud Messaging
>   recebam mensagens. As portas a abrir são: 5228, 5229 e 5230.
>   Normalmente, o FCM usa apenas a porta 5228, mas usa ocasionalmente as
>   portas 5229 e 5230. O FCM não fornece IPs específicos, portanto, você
>   deve autorizar o firewall para aceitar conexões de saída com todos os
>   endereços IP contidos nos blocos IP listados no ASN do Google de
>   15169.